# Moq Unit Testing of Linq Find results in NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I have recently started working on `Moq` for `asp.net mvc`. I get a ***NullReferenceException*** when the `Find` statement is executed. The code snippet is below.

There is a conflict when I try to unit test a Repository class method that has both `linq Find` and `Linq Query` statement. I believe that the last statement for `dbContext.Setup` in case of Students gets prioritized first. If `dbContext.Setup` for Find is placed after dbContext.Setup for Studnets, then Find works but it fails in Linq query for Student(dbContext.Students in query). Otherwise its the opposite. Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod() {
   ////Arrange
   var studentData = new List<Student> { 
      new Student { StudentId = 123, Name = "Demo1" },
       new Student { StudentId = 124, Name = "Demo2" }
   }.AsQueryable();

   mockStudentSet = new Mock<DbSet<Student>>();

   mockStudentSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(studentData.Provider);
   mockStudentSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(studentData.Expression);
   mockStudentSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(studentData.ElementType);
   mockStudentSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(studentData.GetEnumerator());


   dbContext.Setup(m => m.Students.Find(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(new Student() { StudentId = 123 });

   dbContext.Setup(e => e.Students).Returns(mockStudentSet.Object);

}

//Repository Method that is being tested    
public StudentSummary GetStudentSummary(long StudentId) {

    StudentSummary studentSummary = new StudentSummary();
    var result = dbContext.Students.Find(StudentId);
    studentSummary.StudentName = result.Name;

    var myClass = (from mc in dbContext.MyClass
              join s in dbContext.Students on mc.StudentId equals s.StudentId
              where mc.StudentId == StudentId
              select new MyClass
              {
                  //
              }).ToList<MyClass>();

    //Rest of the code
}
```

The variable result in `GetStudentSummary` is null and gets a ***System.NullReferenceException*** there.

Comment: That is what `It.IsAny` will give you, a `null`. Usually `default()`. Put a real `long` in there

Comment: Of course result is null since you can't mock a dbContext to setup it and return a predefined value. You will need to wrap the dbContext in a class and provide an interface to it so you can mock it

Comment: As an aside, I don't think this test has much value. Your mock is very unlikely to behave the same way as Entity Framework, a query that works here might fail on the database.

Comment: That is the standard way to mock an entity framework dbcontext.... I do agree it wont give much value because he is trying to test a linq query, but there is still value. But you have to start somewhere

Comment: You don't really need to be mocking `Find` when you've set up the dbset to return you a list of `Students`, `Find` will use the underlying iterators etc, hence why you mock those out!!

Comment: @CallumLinington The variable `result` is null when i debug it with or without mocking `Find`. However if i move the mock `m.Students.Find` below the mock `e.Students`. The variable `result` will have a Customer.

Comment: Please read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx)