# Mock in unit test returns null at LINQ.Where

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have two classes `Beam` and `Treatment` that I want to match with their value `DateTime TimeStamp`. So in my code I have a LINQ `.Where()` to search for a special TimeStamp and compare it to a pre-sorted list. With real data it workes very good and without any errors, but now I was told to write a unit test for this class and with `Moq` I don't get the expected result.

The line in my code, where it doesn't work is this:

```
Treatment searchedBeam = (Treatment)InputData.Treatments.
    Where(beam => beam.TimeStamp == sortingList[j + i * rangeOfBeams]).FirstOrDefault();
```

The `i,j` are indices from for-loops and run correctly as I saw in debug mode.

In my unit testing code I have this:

```
Mock<ITreatmentGroup> treatGroupMock1;
[SetUp]
public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();

    // --- Create Plan Mock
    // some code here

    // --- Create Treatment Mock
    DateTime time1 = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 12, 00, 00);
    DateTime time2 = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 13, 00, 00);

    Mock<ITreatment> treatMock1 = new Mock<ITreatment>();
    treatMock1.Setup(t => t.TimeStamp).Returns(time1);
    Mock<ITreatment> treatMock2 = new Mock<ITreatment>();
    treatMock2.Setup(t => t.TimeStamp).Returns(time2);

    treatGroupMock1 = new Mock<ITreatmentGroup>();
    treatGroupMock1.Setup(tg => tg.Treatments).Returns(new List<ITreatment>() { treatMock1.Object, treatMock2.Object });
}
```

In debugging I checked that the mocked data are in same structure as the real data. But then comes my test code:

```
[Test]
public void Matched_MatchedAndSortedPlan_FunctionCheck()
{
    IPlan result = Matched.MatchedAndSortedPlan(_planMock.Object, _treatGroupMock1.Object, out IList<string> errors);

    Assert.IsEmpty(errors);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.FractionGroups[0].Beams.Any(f => f.BeamName == "beamMock1"));              
}
```

So I'm calling my method with mocked data and as with real data it should work, but as I mentioned the line with the LINQ expression returns `null` so the `Assert` commands let the unit test fail.

The biggest hint I got is that there are some problems with mocking LINQ expressions, but I don't want to mock a LINQ expression but use it for my solution. Other questions here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013575/linq-firstordefault-on-a-mocked-list) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714152/moq-unit-testing-of-linq-find-results-in-nullreferenceexception) that Google presented me as first hits of my search, I think don't work here.

I hope you have another clue or hint for me.

Comment: Is `Matched` also a Mock or is this a real object ? What is `_planMock`? Where is it defined ? First I'd verify that calls to methods that I've created setup for - were actually done eg : `treatGroupMock1.Verify(...)` etc

Comment: Matched is a real class that I want to test. I was told that for good code development I should write a unit test before I change the class. So `_planMock` is the opposite site of the `Treatment` where the mentioned `Beam` is stored in a list. But I will try your suggestion to use `.Verify()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linq `Where` is working fine. The `searchedBeam` is being assigned `null`  because of the attempt to cast from the mocked interface to the concrete type.

```
                          right here
                              |
                              v
Treatment searchedBeam = (Treatment)InputData.Treatments.
    Where(beam => beam.TimeStamp == sortingList[j + i * rangeOfBeams]).FirstOrDefault();
```

You are casting the returned result to `Treatment` while the items set up in the collection of the test are just mocks of `ITreatment`.

If you are able to create actual instances of `Treatment` without side effects then create and use them for the test

```
[SetUp]
public override void Init() {
    base.Init();

    // --- Create Plan Mock
    // some code here

    // --- Create Treatment Mock
    DateTime time1 = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 12, 00, 00);
    DateTime time2 = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 13, 00, 00);

    var treatMock1 = new Treatment {
        TimeStamp = time1
    };
    var treatMock2 = new Treatment {
        TimeStamp = time2
    };

    treatGroupMock1 = new Mock<ITreatmentGroup>();
    treatGroupMock1.Setup(_ => _.Treatments).Returns(new List<ITreatment>() { treatMock1, treatMock2 });
}
```

That way the cast behaves as expected when exercising the test.

Comment: That works good, but maybe you allow me one question. By creating the structure this way, is using `Moq` necessaryly anymore?

Comment: A combination of moq and actual instances are needed for the test in this particular case. You mock dependencies that have side effects if their instances will cause problems when testing.